# Use Ajax results outside function

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

How can I use results of ajax request outside the ajax function?

I send results to other function, it should normally work.

This is the code I used.

```
function ajaxcall_array(value) { 
    var tmpajaxdata = new Array(); 
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; ++i){ 
        tmpvar=(value[i]) ;  
        tmpajaxdata.push(tmpvar) ; 
        return tmpajaxdata ; 
        } 
        return tmpajaxdata ; 
        alert(tmpajaxdata); 
        console.debug(tmpajaxdata);
} 

function ajaxcall(){
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'ajax.php',             
  data: "name", 
  type:'GET', 
  async:false, 
  dataType: 'json',                 //data format 
  success: function(results)        //on recieve of reply 
  { 
        ajaxdata = ajaxcall_array(results) ;
        return ajaxdata ;
  } 
}); 
return ajaxdata ;
alert(ajaxdata);
} 
ajaxcall();
```

Thanks

Comment: this gets asked numerous times a week and there are numerous links in `Related` right sidebar that answer it

Comment: Once again, AJAX stands for **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML. So, we can't return anything from the ajax call in this way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

This is working, but before your `alert / console.log` you already return the value in `ajaxcall_arrray()`

```
function ajaxcall_array(value) { 
    var tmpajaxdata = new Array(); 
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; ++i){ 
        tmpvar=(value[i]) ;  
        tmpajaxdata.push(tmpvar) ; 
        return tmpajaxdata ; 
    } 
    return tmpajaxdata ; 

    // HERE ALREADY RETURNED
    // CODE BELOW NEVER HIT
    alert(tmpajaxdata); 
    console.debug(tmpajaxdata);
}
```

Comment: removing the return from for loop doesn't do it.