# Updated With JsFiddle: Getting NaN on when I take the average function of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

My array is declared like this

```
var stocks = new Array();
```

I'm getting a list of numbers from google trends and turning it into an array. This is console.log('The stocks are ', stocks);

```
The stocks are  [47, 65, 81, 100, 86, 76, 57, 54, 80, 81, 92, 82, 81, 59, 48, 77, 90, 86]
```

Here's my average function. It returns NaN instead of the average.

```
function avgOut(values) {

    var average = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i = i + 1) {
        average = average + values[i];

    }
    return (average / values.length); // returns NaN
}
```

Edit: Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/caduekL2/

Comment: How the stocks Array is related with the given code

Comment: It doesn't return NaN when I try it: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/1om4svp2/

Comment: Have you checked whether `values` indeed contains the right values? If it is empty, values.length is `0`, and you'll get a division by zero, which results in NaN. Perhaps you passed `stocks` incorrectly to the function.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm using jsonp to retrieve the data. I'll make a fiddle...

Comment: Is your array possibly being sent into the function as a string? Your code does work in a fiddle.

Comment: Does your array contain numbers or strings?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/caduekL2/

Comment: You are trying to use the data before the response has arrived. If you use the function where you have the data, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/caduekL2/1/

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387415/use-ajax-results-outside-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guffa is correct, your average function is working correctly. You're getting NaN because the call to avgOut is happening BEFORE the call to Google's server returns.

Using JSONP makes the whole thing asynchronous, and you have to pay close attention to when you use variables.

The console.log(avgOut(stocks)) should happen in your callback function, which in this case looks like it starts at line 22 in that JSFiddle link.

Comment: yeah, i was typing mine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jvq1916d/ 
Just put `console.log(avgOut(stocks));` right after `console.log('The stocks are ', stocks);`